# How to store my values to the php database and no error or output

Tags: mysql

I think the problem is with the mysqli_query. The code gives no error but if there was a problem with the database a "Failed to connect to MySQL"
output will come out.

And if there was a problem with the insert code a Registration Failed out will come out it is doing neither of them. It simply flickers resets everything and then nothing.

```
<?php
    define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASS' ,'');
    define('DB_NAME', 'registrations');
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }

    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $division = $_POST['division'];
        $programme = $_POST['programme'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $phone_no = $_POST['phone_no'];

        $msg=mysqli_query($con,"insert into register('firstname','lastname','age','email','gender','division','programme','department','phone_no') values ('$firstname','$lastname','$age','$email','$gender','$division','$programme','$department','$phone_no')");    

        if($msg)
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Registered Successfully")</script>';
        }
        else
        {
            '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Registration Failed")</script>';
        }

    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration Form</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Register</h2>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="POST" action="register.php">



            <div class="input-group">
                <label>First Name</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="txt" name="firstname"  required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Last Name</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="txt" name="lastname"  required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Age</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="txt" name="age" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group"><br>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="txt" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Gender</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Division</label><br>
                <select name="division">
                    <option value="">--select--</option>
                    <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
                    <option value="Extension">Extension</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Programme</label><br>
                <select name="programme">
                    <option value="">--select--</option>
                    <option value="Degree">Degree</option>
                    <option value="Masters">Masters</option>
                    <option value="tvt">tvt</option>
                </select>
            </div>      
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Department</label><br>
                <select name="department">
                    <option value="">--select--</option>
                    <option value="ComputerScience">Computer Science</option>
                    <option value="Accounting">Accounting</option>
                    <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
                    <option value="Tourism">Tourism</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Phone Number</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="txt" name="phone_no" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="register">Register</button>
            </div>      
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Corrected the tag to `mysql` (this is **not** `sql-server` related code .....)

Comment: If you see "Failure to Connect" first try different connection strings in $con then try your instance of mysql, make sure a service is running, make sure you can browse the database with the same db connection string your query uses on whatever browser you have e.g. Workbench

Comment: Why do you have 2 action attributes on the form element? Where is the form data actually getting posted?

Comment: the action=''" was an accident but i don't know what you mean about the form data getting posted. forgive me i am a newbie to php. it only been two days.

Comment: When the user clicks the Submit button the form data gets posted to a script on the server indicated in the form's action attribute. It looks like you want the data to post back to the current page, so your action attribute should be the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

apparently it is because of the radio button i changed it to combo box and now works perfectly. i still don't understand why.
and i also removed the action = ""

Comment: Strange. This code should fail. You have confused backticks with inverted commas.